# Cell Representation of a galvanic cell:

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I know basic cell representations of galvanic cells and can identify the anode/cathode. But here's a weird representation that I encountered and couldn't understand it:

$$\ce{Pt | H2(g)}(\pu{1.0 atm})\ce{ | HX || KCl(1M) | Hg2Cl2(s) | Hg | Pt}$$

What does this actually translate into?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably know that the notation for galvanic cell reads from left to right as *anode* || *cathode*, where **||** typically denotes a salt bridge.

Within each half cell, different phases are separated by **|**.

In your case, the anode is a platinum rod in an acidic solution under a hydrogen atmosphere. This is a [Standard hydrogen electrode (SHE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_hydrogen_electrode).

The cathode consists of a platinum rod which is contact with a layer of mercury and a layer of solid mercury(I) chloride. It is an aqueous cell with 1M KCl solution as the medium. This electrode is known as [Saturated calomel electrode (SCE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_calomel_electrode).

Both electrodes are used as reference electrodes.